# Is it possible to share resources between mobile air applications?

Tags: android

I am developing a series of language learning games for mobile. First on Android then later for Apple devices.

Each game has about 1000 sound files for different words that can be studied. These take up about 8MB, while the rest of the game is only about 1MB. So I would love to find a way to share the sound files for users who install more than 1 game.

Obviously if they install all of the games individually this wont be possible, as they will need to download the full game from the play store with no way to know if the sounds are already installed... however I plan to create a game launcher app... this would be one app that could be used to download (if they haven't already) and launch (if they have) the other individually installed apps, register accounts, etc.

So if they use this launcher (which includes the soundfiles) could I then download the other individual 1MB games and share the sounds between them?

Perhaps it would possible to control the folder structure such as having them install as: 
MyCompanyName/game1 MyCompanyName/game2 then have each game reference the MyCompanyName/sound folder?

Or is there any other method?

Thanks for any help.